# To tab a txt file with a python header

Tags: python, split, delimiter

Python is a new language for me and I'm having some difficulty in tabulating raw data in a txt file. I would like to leave as below:

```
ID,company_name,cnpj
1123,'XPTO',123456478
4354,'WWWW',243425566
```

My data in the txt file is as follows:
`{'_id': {'$oid': '5c597e54b74db23f476e0db4'}, 'company_name': 'CALTABIANO MOTORS PINHEIROS LTDA', 'cnpj': '987654321111', 'description': '206-2 - Sociedade EmpresÃ¡ria Limitada', 'telephone': '(11) 3660-7084', 'andress': 'Rua Major Quedinho 90', 'zip_code': '05.477-000', 'city': 'SAO PAULO', 'state': 'SP', 'address': 'AV DOUTORA RUTH CARDOSO', 'option': 'save'}{'_id': {'$oid': '5c59eb24b74db279878f3806'}, 'company_name': 'KCC', 'cnpj': '0000000000000', 'description': 'xxx', 'telephone': '00000000', 'andress': 'Rua Major Quedinho 90', 'zip_code': '0000000', 'city': 'SÃ£o Paulo', 'state': 'SÃ£o Paulo'}`

My code:

```
with open(filename_txt, 'w') as arquivo:
    for client in data_clients:
        arquivo.write(str(client))
        #print(client)
    arquivo.close()


with open(filename_txt) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\n")
    for i in f:
        reader1=csv.reader(f, delimiter=";")
        print(i)
```

Comment: The source of the data needed is unclear as it doesn't appear txt file. Please [edit] your question and clarify where each column of data comes from.

Comment: @Martineau My data source is json file.

Comment: Yes, it looks like one — so why are you calling it a txt file? Regardless, even if it's a JSON file, the information you want it doesn't contain the information you want to put in the file you "would like to leave".

Comment: I recorded the contents of the json file in a txt without formatting and would like to tab this file in txt

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't express myself well. I wrote the contents of a json file in a txt, but I need to format it in columns .

Comment: I can see where `company_name` and `cnpj` come from but not `ID`.

Comment: The ID is the '_id': {'$oid': '5c597e54b74db23f476e0db4'}